# *ngIf with async pipe for observable from BehaviorSubject seem to activate incorrectly until data is loaded

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

If the array in response is empty I want to display a message, otherwise the elements of the array.

In case the response has a non-empty array the ***ngIf** condition evalutes to  **true** and the message is displayed **until** the data is loaded.

Html template snippet:

```
<div *ngIf="personalAndStarredBookmarks$ && (personalAndStarredBookmarks$ | async)?.size === 0; else personalBookmarksList" class="missing-category-bookmarks-message  alert alert-info">
  <p>No bookmarks yet</p>
</div>
<ng-template #personalBookmarksList>
  <app-async-bookmark-list [bookmarks]="personalAndStarredBookmarks$" [shownSize]="10" [userData]="userData"></app-async-bookmark-list>
</ng-template>
```

Component snippet:

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

export class PersonalBookmarksListComponent implements OnInit {

  personalAndStarredBookmarks$: Observable<List<Bookmark>>;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.personalAndStarredBookmarks$ = this.personalBookmarksStore.getPersonalBookmarks();
  }
  ...
}
```

The store uses a *BehaviourSubject* where it holds the response from a service that actually does the HTTP call.

Store snippet

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonalBookmarksStore {

  private _personalBookmarks: BehaviorSubject<List<Bookmark>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));

  constructor(private personalBookmarkService: PersonalBookmarkService,
              private keycloakService: KeycloakService
  ) {
    keycloakService.loadUserProfile().then(keycloakProfile => {
      this.userId = keycloakProfile.id;
      this.loadInitialData();
    });
  }

  private loadInitialData() {
    this.personalBookmarkService.getAllPersonalBookmarks(this.userId)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          let bookmarks: Bookmark[] = <Bookmark[]>data;
          this._personalBookmarks.next(List(bookmarks));
        },
        err => console.error('Error retrieving bookmarks', err)
      );
  }

  getPersonalBookmarks(): Observable<List<Bookmark>> {
    return this._personalBookmarks.asObservable();
  }
  ...
}
```

**If I am calling directly the Service (not the Store) in the component it behaves as expected...**

Comment: I think you intended to write `.length`, not `.size`, in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the initialisation of the BehaviorSubject with an **empty** list, which gets emitted and the condition evaluates to true:

```
private _personalBookmarks: BehaviorSubject<List<Bookmark>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));
```

Fix - init the BehaviorSubject with a `null` or `undefined`

```
private _personalBookmarks: BehaviorSubject<List<Bookmark>> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your template to handle the async calls efficiently by assigning a local variable as

```
<ng-content*ngIf="personalAndStarredBookmarks$ | async as personalAndStarredBookmarks">
    <div *ngIf="personalAndStarredBookmarks.size === 0; else personalBookmarksList" 
        class="missing-category-bookmarks-message  alert alert-info">
        <p>No bookmarks yet</p>
    </div>
    <ng-template #personalBookmarksList>
        <app-async-bookmark-list [bookmarks]="personalAndStarredBookmarks" [shownSize]="10"
            [userData]="userData">
        </app-async-bookmark-list>
    </ng-template>
<ng-content>
```

With this, you can efficiently handle all the conditions and the main content loads only after the async call is resolved.

See a [DEMO HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-with-ngif-else)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question for clarity, but this should be caught through the use of the safety operator (?) and should evaluate to false, right?... see https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: @Adrian you need not assign your `BehaviorSubject` null initially and follow the approach I posted. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Hei @Saksham, yes the culprit was the empty array at the initialisation of the BehaviorSubject. I figured it out before sorry, see my answer and solution...

Comment: @Adrian yes I did see your solution but the one I have implemented above looks after availability more efficiently with less number of comparisons.

Comment: I don't see how it is more performant in comparison to `(personalAndStarredBookmarks$ | async)?.size === 0`, which waits for async operation to complete and does the comparison... It's true you don't need to use the async pipe down the line but in this situation the code is more verbose.... Do you have a link?